How do I apply a color from characters in a column from a data table to data points in a scatter plot using ggplot2
I'm completely new to R and I would like to create a plot using ggplot2. My aim is to have a scatter plot with x=CAO and Y=F, I also need to have the data points to have a specific color depending on their name in column RN. I could do it manually but my actual dataset has thousand of entries...
  RN                      CAO F                 
   <chr>                 <dbl> <chr>             
 1 HAWAIITE               52.7 4.64
 2 HAWAIITE               53.9 3.75              
 3 MUGEARITE              53.8 3.59              
 4 MUGEARITE              53.4 3.45              
 5 BENMOREITE             53.5 4.2               
 6 BENMOREITE             53.3 2.00                 
 7 TRACHYTE               53.2 3.68              
 8 HARZBURGITE, XENOLITH  52.2 4.82              
 9 WEHLERITE, XENOLITH    51.9 5.51              
10 DUNITE, XENOLITH       54.0 4.40

Thank you for your help!
Here is my code now, I get the scatter plot but all points have the same color.
georoc %>%
select(RN,CAO,F)

ggplot(georoc, aes(x = CAO, y = F ,colour = "RN"))+
  geom_point(size = 4, alpha = 0.8, stroke = 1, aes(color ="RN"))  +
  theme(legend.position= "none") +      
  labs(title = "CAO vs F",
       x = "CAO", y = "F")


Welcome to SO! Try without quotes, i.e. use colour = RN. For more help and for future questions please provide a minimal reproducible example including a snippet of your input data best shared using dput() or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset.

^ aes(color = "RN") means "the color should be mapped to the string 'RN' for all data", whereas aes(color = RN) means "the color should be mapped to the values in the column RN"

Based on @stefan and @JonSpring answers
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  RN = c("HAWAIITE", "HAWAIITE", "MUGEARITE", "MUGEARITE", "BENMOREITE", "BENMOREITE", "TRACHYTE", "HARZBURGITE, XENOLITH", "WEHLERITE, XENOLITH", "DUNITE, XENOLITH"),
  CAO = c(52.7, 53.9, 53.8, 53.4, 53.5, 53.3, 53.2, 52.2, 51.9, 54.0),
  F = c(4.64, 3.75, 3.59, 3.45, 4.2, 2.00, 3.68, 4.82, 5.51, 4.40)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x = CAO, y = F))+
  geom_point(size = 4, alpha = 0.8, stroke = 1, aes(color = RN))  +
  theme(legend.position= "none") +      
  labs(title = "CAO vs F",
       x = "CAO", y = "F")


Created on 2024-06-07 with reprex v2.1.0
